# Python SQLite3 extracting key and values in JSON file

Tags: python, json, sqlite, dictionary, key-value

I am trying to extract keys and values of a JSON file. However, i am having trouble extracting the correct key and values. I have to extract and create a schema in SQLite.

This is a sample of the JSON file:

```
"entities": {"hashtags": [{"text": "#Hello world", "indices": [0, 19]}], "symbols": [], "user_mentions": [], "urls": [{"url": "www.co/DtjRrIzPTK"................
```

This is my code:

```
f = open('tweet.json',)
data = json.load(f)
for index, i in enumerate(data):
    entities = i['entities']
    tweet_id = i['id']
    types = list(entities.keys())
    for t in types:
        if t in entities_types:
            if entities[t] != []:
                for index,(key,value) in enumerate(entities[t][0].items()):
                    if index == 0:
                        type = key
                        type_value =  i['full_text']
                    elif key == 'indices':
                        start_index = value[0]
                        end_index = value[1]

                query = '''
              INSERT INTO entities (tweet_id, type, value, start_index,end_index)
                VALUES
                (?,?,?,?,?);
              '''
                c.execute(query,(tweet_id,type,type_value,start_index,end_index))  

conn.commit()
with conn:
  c.execute("SELECT * FROM entities")
  print(c.fetchall())
```

This is what I am returned with:

`[(1, 1408411651238371337, 'text', "#Hello World, 0, 19), (2, 1408411651238371337, 'url', 'www.co/DtjRrIzPTK', 211, 234).....`

However, it is wrong. I should expect it to be:

`[(1, 1408411651238371337, 'Hashtags', "#Hello World, 0, 19), (2, 1408411651238371337, 'url', 'www.co/DtjRrIzPTK', 211, 234).....`